# Function call not ambiguous if {} is used

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, curly-braces, list-initialization

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

// 1st function
void f(int i, int j = 10){
    printf("Hello World what");
};

void f(std::vector<int>){
    printf("Hello World vec");
};

void f(std::deque<int>){
    printf("Hello World deq");
};

int main()
{
    f({});
    return 0;
}
```

If the 1st function is commented out I get `ambiguous call` when compiling. If not commented out, 1st function is called. Why is `{}` implicitly converted to `int`?

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/rkhR0NiBD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I would like to delete this post because it's false (sorry for that, I forgot that the initialiser list constructor of vector/deque is not a template). Unfortunately I cannot do this as long as it is the accepted answer.

---

Single argument constructors to `std::vector` and `std::deque` are explicit. Automatic type deduction is not possible for an empty initialiser list, that eliminates all ways of matching the `f(std::vector<int>)` and `f(std::deque<int>)` overloads.

So constructing an int is the only match.

Comment: This is not correct. The `initializer_list` constructors are not explicit. In fact, they both match, hence the ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is `{}` implicitly converted to `int`?

This is [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), as the effect the parameter is value-initialized (zero-initialized) as `0`. `int` could be initialized from (empty) braced-init-list, just as `int i{};` or `int i = {};`.

> 7. in a function call expression, with braced-init-list used as an argument and list-initialization initializes the function parameter

For `f(std::vector<int>)` and `f(std::deque<int>)` to be called, a user-defined conversion (by the constructor of `std::vector` and `std::deque` taking `std::initializer_list`) is required; then the 1st overload wins in overload resolution.